# For loop not accessing JSON Objects properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

For some reason when I finish the quiz the proper JSON object property isn't being accessed. Once the string is identified its supposed to access the property. If I hard code it . [0], [1], etc it works. How can I fix this? Also, how can I make this code more succinct? I feel there might be another way besides using so many if statements. Thanks.

The object in question

```
var personTypes = [{ 
        type : "INTJ",
        typeInfo: "Imaginative and strategic thinkers, with a plan for everything.",

        },
        {type : "INTP",
        typeInfo: "Innovative inventors with an unquenchable thirst for knowledge.",

        },
        {type : "ENTJ",
        typeInfo: "Bold, imaginative and strong-willed leaders, always finding a way – or making one.",

        },
        {type : "ENTP",
        typeInfo: "Smart and curious thinkers who cannot resist an intellectual challenge.",

        },
        {type : "INFJ",
        typeInfo: "Quiet and mystical, yet very inspiring and tireless idealists",

        },
        {type : "INFP",
        typeInfo: "Poetic, kind and altruistic people, always eager to help a good cause.",

        },
        {type : "ENFJ",
        typeInfo: "Charismatic and inspiring leaders, able to mesmerize their listeners.",

        },
        {type : "ENFP",
        typeInfo: "Enthusiastic, creative and sociable free spirits, who can always find a reason to smile.",

        },
        {type : "ISTJ",
        typeInfo: "Practical and fact-minded individuals, whose reliability cannot be doubted.",

        },
        {type : "ISFJ",
        typeInfo: "Very dedicated and warm protectors, always ready to defend their loved ones.",

        },
        {type : "ESTJ",
        typeInfo: "Excellent administrators, unsurpassed at managing things – or people.",

        },
        {type : "ESFJ",
        typeInfo: "Extraordinarily caring, social and popular people, always eager to help.",

        },
        {type : "ISTP",
        typeInfo: "Bold and practical experimenters, masters of all kinds of tools.",

        },
        {type : "ISFP",
        typeInfo: "Flexible and charming artists, always ready to explore and experience something new.",

        },
        {type : "ESTP",
        typeInfo: "Smart, energetic and very perceptive people, who truly enjoy living on the edge",

        },
        {type : "ESFP",
        typeInfo: "Spontaneous, energetic and enthusiastic people – life is never boring around them.",

        },
];
```

Accessing the object

```
 // once done with quiz
   if (questionNum === 3) {

        //concat radio inputs
        var typeConcat = this.ei + this.sn+ this.tf+ this.pj;
        //output concat to screen
        $("p").show();
        $("h2").text("Your type is " + typeConcat);



            //use this data inside the <p>
        for (i = 0; i < personTypes.length; i++) {    
            if (typeConcat=="INTJ") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
            if (typeConcat=="INTP") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ENTJ") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ENTP") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="INFJ") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="INFP") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ENFJ") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ENFP") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ISTJ") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ISFJ") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ESTJ") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ESFJ") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ISTP") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ISFP") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ESTP") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
             if (typeConcat=="ESFP") {
                $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please add the object as well.

Comment: you could replace the `if` statements with a  `switch`...(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need all of the if statements, when you have the type specified, right? This would work just the same.

EDIT: And don't forget to include `var` before the `i = 0`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < personTypes.length; i++) {    
    if (typeConcat==personTypes[i].type) {
        $("p").text(personTypes[i].typeInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly the solution! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

A more succinct version would be putting the types in a hashmap and access the type by the typeConcat given:

```
var personTypes = {
  INTJ: "Imaginative and strategic thinkers, with a plan for everything.",
  INTP: "Innovative inventors with an unquenchable thirst for knowledge.",
  ENTJ: "Bold, imaginative and strong-willed leaders, always finding a way – or making one.",
  ENTP: "Smart and curious thinkers who cannot resist an intellectual challenge.",
  INFJ: "Quiet and mystical, yet very inspiring and tireless idealists",
  INFP: "Poetic, kind and altruistic people, always eager to help a good cause.",
  ENFJ: "Charismatic and inspiring leaders, able to mesmerize their listeners.",
  ENFP: "Enthusiastic, creative and sociable free spirits, who can always find a reason to smile.",
  ISTJ: "Practical and fact-minded individuals, whose reliability cannot be doubted.",
  ISFJ: "Very dedicated and warm protectors, always ready to defend their loved ones.",
  ESTJ: "Excellent administrators, unsurpassed at managing things – or people.",
  ESFJ: "Extraordinarily caring, social and popular people, always eager to help.",
  ISTP: "Bold and practical experimenters, masters of all kinds of tools.",
  ISFP: "Flexible and charming artists, always ready to explore and experience something new.",
  ESTP: "Smart, energetic and very perceptive people, who truly enjoy living on the edge",
  ESFP: "Spontaneous, energetic and enthusiastic people – life is never boring around them."
}

$("p").text(personTypes[typeConcat]);
```